# How can I send multiple messages to a running service?

Tags: android, background-service

I have created a voice recording service. I have implemented all methods like `startRecording()` and `stopRecording()` , `saveFile()` etc...

I want to start recording when I send first notification from Firebase and stop recording by second notification and save the file when recording was stopped. This is my current solution by starting and stopping service in **FirebaseNotificationService**:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        final String tag = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTag();

        if (tag.equals("startRecording")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecorderService.class);
            startForegroundService(intent);
        }

        if (tag.equals("stopRecording")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecorderService.class);
            stopService(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

I know that I can start recording onStartCommand like this in **RecorderService**:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    startRecording();
    // and show sticky notification
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

and stop recording

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopRecording();
    saveFile();
}
```

But I have another problem: How can I send more messages to a running service? For example how can I handle PAUSE in such service? or how can I call `stopRecording()` and `saveFile()` method before destroying the service? In brief is there another option to remotley handle a service rather than **startCommand** and **destroy**?

In this special case I want to call `stopRecording()` by another notification and call `saveFile()` with 3rd notification and finally stop the service by 4th notification. I don't want you to write methods to do that. I am just looking for a way to communicatie with a running service. Thanks.

**Edit:** I know other options like bind and unbind events but I am looking for a general way to cummunicate with service not using its prepared events.

Comment: Did you try answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of posting actions as `Intent` you need to use bound `Service`. It will gives you instance of `Service` binder, which you can use as a callback to your service and send hundred of events/messages.

Check [the documentation about it](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services).